# Passing objects with same name to dictionary is modifying old objects (pass by reference)

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I am building a file system analyzer and I have a class named `HashableHeap`, it overrides the `__hash__` function to hash with file extensions. I have a dictionary that maps extensions to heaps. For example .jpg heap needs to hold jpg objects and when I hash for .jpg it should give me the corresponding heap.

The problem is: When I encounter an extension thats not in the dictionary's keys, I create a new heap and add it. When the code tries to create and add a new heap, it modifies the first one as well. For example: let's say it first adds a .json heap to dict. then it encounters a .sql file and creates a new heap with the same name. When it adds the new heap, .sql files get's added to .json heap as well. All heaps are the same content with different keys.

I think it is about references, I tried to delete new heap object but it changed nothing. Maybe I need a pass by value like behavior but I am a beginner with Python.

```
def add_to_dictionary(directory, abs_path):
    # Creates a file obj from path and adds to heap
    for file in directory:
        try:
            f = File(os.path.join(abs_path, file))
            if f.extension in extension_dictionary.keys():  # check if the corresponding heap exists for extension x
                hashable_heap = extension_dictionary[f.extension]
                hashable_heap.total_size += f.size
                heapq.heappush(hashable_heap.heap, f)
            elif f.extension != '':  # if the heap does not exist, create and add with current file
                new_heap = HashableHeap(f.extension)
                new_heap.total_size = f.size
                extension_dictionary[f.extension] = new_heap
                heapq.heappush(extension_dictionary[f.extension].heap, f)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(os.path.join(abs_path, file))
            print('No permission')
```

Here is the code for `HashableHeap` since it is requested:

```
class HashableHeap:
    # wrapper class for heaps, required for the extension based hashing
    heap = []
    extension = ''
    total_size = 0

    def __init__(self, extension):
        self.extension = extension

    def __hash__(self):
        hash(self.extension)

    def __lt__(self, other):  # Comparator of the heaps by their sizes
        return self.total_size > other.total_size
```

PyCharm Debug Screenshot:

[image: PyCharm Debug Screenshot]

Comment: You should show the code for HashableHeap.

Comment: Added the HashableHeap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between class variables and instance variables.  Class variables are created outside the `__init__` function and are shared across all the instances of the class.  That is rarely what you want.  Instance variables are created inside the `__init__` function.  They are unique to each instance of the class.

You are creating the variable `heap` outside of the `__init__` method, so it is shared by all instances of HashableHeap.  That's exactly the behavior you're seeing.

Try this:

```
class HashableHeap:
    # wrapper class for heaps, required for the extension based hashing
    def __init__(self, extension):
        self.heap = []
        self.total_size = 0
        self.extension = extension
 # Everything else is the same
```

There are some subtleties regarding class versus instance variables.  When you assign to a variable, such as your line of code `self.extension = extension`, that actually creates an instance variable that hides the class variable of the same name.  You need to read up on this if you want to understand this concept thoroughly.

As an aside, your HashableHeap function doesn't actually do anything useful.  Python dictionaries already use a hashing algorithm on their keys automatically.  When you insert a key:value pair into a dictionary the key gets hashed for you.